# Merge [ebay-api] into [ebay]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[paypal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-api) goes to [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) so why not have [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) go to [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay)? No need to have the duplicate tags.

Comment: Backwards. Backwards. Backwards. Backwards. Check if ebay have any good api questions, retag, kill ebay with fire. i. e. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18266373/792066) has nothing to do with ebay's api

Comment: The tag [tag:ebay-api] has 258 questions, the tag [tag:ebay] has 823 questions, 124 of them have both. So it would be easier to merge the other direction but I agree that a questions tagged paypal-api is more likely to be on topic for SO than paypal so the cleanup effort to merge to paypal-api would be worth it.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with this, because you can also design and add some [limited JavaScript code](https://www.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-policies/javascript-policy?id=4247) to the auction pages at eBay. Those questions are not ebay-api questions.