# Should we auction off [ebay]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I don't see how the [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) tag is on topic here. I don't think we should have tags for sites (generally). The tag should be for an API that lets you talk to a site, and there is already an [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) tag.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Perhaps, but [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) is almost always a better tag for describing the contents of the question.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   I don't think so. The specific technology/API is what's on topic, not the name of the site.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Maybe a little, but again [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) is much more meaningful.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   I suppose.

---

I came across a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316034/merge-ebay-api-into-ebay#comment302237_316034) on this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316034/merge-ebay-api-into-ebay) that proposed the following:

> Check if ebay have any good api questions, retag, kill ebay with fire.

I suggest doing that.

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to clean up and then synonym it to [ebay-api]

Comment: @Machavity 280 tagged [ebay] and [api], fixing that helps two tags ...

Comment: It really doesn't matter if a tag is named after a site. What matters is if the questions asked in that tag are on-topic, clearly defined, well scoped and gets good answers.

Comment: On ebay you can also design and add some limited javascript the auction pages, I'm noth sure whether this will fix into ebay-api.

Comment: @MrTux yeah, I noticed that when looking at a couple questions unrelated to the API. Do you think we should keep the [ebay] tag for those questions, or create a new tag?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +59/-7. A1 (saying Yes) +26/0

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +126/-13. A1 (saying Yes) +76/0. A2 (saying Yes) +40/0 A3 (saying Yes) +1/-1. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: It would be helpful if folks editing tags left a comment about the reason being "burninantion", so people like me don't wonder why someone is resurrecting 3+ year old questions with tag only edits ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- [Questions tagged [ebay]+[api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay+api) can have both tags removed and [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) added where missing.
- [Questions tagged [ebay] containing 'api'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+api+is%3Aquestion) can *probably all* have [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) removed and [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) added.
- There are a [lot of questions about the eBay SDK that is used to interact with the API](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+sdk&mixed=0), these need to be tagged as [ebay-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-sdk).
- The questions related to customizing eBay pages using templates, these can be tagged with [ebay-design-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-design-templates).
- There were some questions related to using eBay with Magento, these can be tagged with [m2e-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2e-pro).

## Progress:

The [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=ebay),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195547)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=370156)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 78):

- [258 questions tagged [ebay]+[api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay+api) can have both tags removed and [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) added where missing.
- [~659 questions tagged [ebay] containing 'api'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+api+is%3Aquestion) can *probably all* have [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay) removed and [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) added.
- [~420 questions tagged [ebay] not containing 'api'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+-api+is%3Aquestion) might need to be retagged and possibly closed. [As MrTux said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370156/should-we-auction-off-ebay/370158?noredirect=1#comment604085_370156), some of them are about CSS and JS problems for customising your own pages on the eBay site.

I'm not entirely sure why the numbers are 659 and 420 when there are only 1060 questions tagged [ebay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay).

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: To work efficiently, it might be best just to review those 420 questions, close or remove the tag where appropriate, then add a synonym from [tag:ebay] to [tag:ebay-api]. While tagging ebay-api + api is a bit redundant, it's not harmful, and that's likely a lot faster than reviewing all of them.

Comment: Presumably 17 [ebay] questions contain 'api', and don't contain 'api'...

Comment: @Stijn The ~659 questions tagged [ebay] containing api include the questions that are tagged [ebay] and [api].

Comment: @JL2210 then shouldn't the questions tagged [ebay] not containing 'api' also exclude the questions tagged [ebay] and [api]? Either way, it was just something I noticed and not important :)

Answer (score 41):

I agree that eBay needs to be burninated. I went through some of the eBay questions that were positively scored. Apart from the eBay API that the OP and the other answer mentions:

- There are a [lot of questions about the eBay SDK that is used to interact with the API](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bebay%5D+sdk&mixed=0), these need to be tagged as [ebay-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-sdk).
- The questions related to customizing eBay pages using templates, these can be tagged with [ebay-store-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-store-templates).
- There were some questions related to using eBay with Magento, these can be tagged with [m2e-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2e-pro).
- There were a couple of questions about the eBay RSS feeds, and eBay Merchant Integration Platform. We would need to create tags for these if required (but on a high level glance, it seemed like it was not required)
- Most of the remaining questions were places where either the tag was superfluous or the post was off-topic.

Comment: So, it needs to be done by hand.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be done by hand. There's no tools for us to mass remove a tag and substitute it with a different tag ...

Comment: Indeed but see other highly voted answer; it appears we can bot-handle all but ~420 of them.

Comment: @Joshua, that'd be awesome, but there's no way to that without writing a bot...

Comment: Yeah there is. Burn to zero using the filtered query then add synonym and remove it again. I'd be glad to greasemonkey it but I don't want to bump 600+ questions for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a widespread consensus that company-specific tags usually don't work very well on the site. For example, [the Apple and Microsoft tags were blacklisted awhile back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags) following a [burnination effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/should-we-burninate-the-apple-tag).

In short, these tags rarely accurately describe on-topic questions. After all, questions about the eBay SDK and the eBay API are presumably on-topic here, but questions about the company are not. That being said, people should just use more specific tags for what they're actually asking about.

Admittedly, [there has been at least one exception to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352209/burninate-the-cisco-tag), but by and large company-specific tags have been removed. It seems rather arbitrary to say that we should get rid of the [Microsoft] and [Apple] tags but keep [ebay] as a tag.

I say we let this one go the same way as the other company-specific names and get rid of it.